# Recyclerview in fragment not loading after screen rotate

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, orientation, screen-rotation

I want to save my fragment with recycler view, to restore it whlie screen rotate. I was looking for instructions in the net and I get:

In my Fragment

```
private Parcelable recyclerViewState;

@Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            list.getLayoutManager().onRestoreInstanceState(recyclerViewState);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        recyclerViewState = layoutManager.onSaveInstanceState();
    }
```

in my Activity

```
//onCreate
if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().getFragment(savedInstanceState, LIST_USERS_FRAGMENT);
        }

@Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        getSupportFragmentManager().getFragment(outState, LIST_USERS_FRAGMENT);
    }
```

I was debbuging and it looks fine, however while I rotate my screen I get blank fragment, with no recycler view. Could You help me investigate why it's happening ?

Answer (score 0):

The default behavior in  Android is destroying all the attached fragments on configuration changes. To bypass fragment recreation you should use setRetainInstance(true) in the OnCreate callback of the fragment.

Answer (score 0):

There are a different options to handle the orientation changes:

1. Lock screen orientation

   ```
   <activity
    android:name="com.example.test.activity.MainActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
   ```
2. Prevent Activity to recreated

   ```
   <activity
    android:name="com.example.test.activity.MainActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"/>
   ```
3. Save basic state

   ```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity{

    private static final String SELECTED_ITEM_POSITION = "ItemPosition";
    private int mPosition;

       @Override
        protected void onSaveInstanceState(final Bundle outState) {
            super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

            // Save the state of item position
             outState.putInt(SELECTED_ITEM_POSITION, mPosition);   
        }

        @Override
        protected void onRestoreInstanceState(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

            // Read the state of item position
            mPosition = savedInstanceState.gettInt(SELECTED_ITEM_POSITION);
        }
   }
   ```
4. Save complex objects

Override

```
  onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()

  getLastNonConfigurationInstance()
```

After API level 13 these methods have been deprecated in favor of the more Fragment’s setRetainInstance(boolean) capability, which provides a much cleaner and modular means of retaining objects during configuration changes.